# Splitting email accounts between qmail and remote exchange on single domain

Tags: email, smtp, exchange-server, office365, mail-server

Need some help configuring the mail server on our dedicated web server. We are currently using just qmail but purchased Office365 Exchange licenses to transfer <10 accounts over while still using qmail. Right now I have both sides of it setup. If I switch the priority level in the MX record in the DNS settings I can switch from using qmail to the remote exchange server but then the rest of the email accounts only on qmail are unable to receive anything. I can send email but not receive through qmail when the remote exchange server is top priority. Is there a way to make them play nice?

Answer (score 0):

Just point the mx record to your qmail server and remove the mx records for Office 365.

Then configure an email forwarding from qmail to your instant access addresses at Office 365.

In Office 365 add your domain as accepted domain of type "internal relay".